# Margin issue on mobile view

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with margins.
Even tho body and html is set to margin:0 and padding: 0, when I switch to mobile view it add a 5-10px margin to the right for the whole page.
I'm really lost here.
I tried checking all the containers if they have margin or anything like that, also set the containers to 100% width, but removed that. I tried border-boxing etc. nothing seemed to work.
https://silly-goldwasser-47fc36.netlify.app/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Pecsi Mediacio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick-theme.css"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/48a88d4550.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
</head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a class="logo" href="/">
        <img src="./assets/svg/logo.svg" alt="dr.bokor_beatrix_logo_pecsi_mediacio" />
      </a>
      <nav>
          <a href="/">Főoldal</a>
          <a href="/Pages/mediacio-menete.html">A mediáció menete</a>
          <a href="#section2">Üzleti mediáció</a>
          <a href="#section2">Családjogi mediáció</a>
          <a href="#section3">Rólam</a>
        <a class="fancy-btn" href="#section4"><span class="button_text1">Kapcsolat</span></a>
      </nav>

<nav id="nav" class="nav" role="navigation">

            <!-- ACTUAL NAVIGATION MENU -->
            <ul class="nav__menu" id="menu" tabindex="-1" aria-label="main navigation" hidden>
              <li class="nav__item"><a href="/" class="nav__link">Főoldal</a></li>
              <li class="nav__item"><a href="/Pages/mediacio-menete.html" class="nav__link">A mediáció menete</a></li>
              <li class="nav__item"><a href="/Pages/uzleti-mediacio.html" class="nav__link">Üzleti Mediáció</a></li>
              <li class="nav__item"><a href="/Pages/csaladjogi-mediacio.html" class="nav__link">Családjogi mediáció</a></li>
              <li class="nav__item"><a href="/Pages/rolam.html" class="nav__link">Rólam</a></li>
            </ul>
            
            <!-- MENU TOGGLE BUTTON -->
            <a href="#nav" class="nav__toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menu">
              <svg class="menuicon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
                <title>Toggle Menu</title>
                <g>
                  <line class="menuicon__bar" x1="13" y1="16.5" x2="37" y2="16.5"/>
                  <line class="menuicon__bar" x1="13" y1="24.5" x2="37" y2="24.5"/>
                  <line class="menuicon__bar" x1="13" y1="24.5" x2="37" y2="24.5"/>
                  <line class="menuicon__bar" x1="13" y1="32.5" x2="37" y2="32.5"/>
                  <circle class="menuicon__circle" r="23" cx="25" cy="25" />
                </g>
              </svg>
            </a>
            
            <!-- ANIMATED BACKGROUND ELEMENT -->
            <div class="splash"></div>
            
          </nav>
    </header>
    
    <main>
      <!-- HERO SECTION -->

      <section class="hero_section">
        <div class="textBox">
          <h1>Alternatív,<br> konfliktuskezelési<br> módszer</h1>
          <p class="elso_bekezdes">
            A szemben álló felek egy harmadik. pártatlak személy segítségével <br>
            találják meg a meoldást vitájuk rendezésére.
          </p>
          <a class="fancy-btn" href="#section1"><span class="button_text2">Tovább</span></a>
          <div class="title_holder">
            <p><span class="title_holder_first">dr bokor beatrix ügyvéd, mediátor </span><br>
              Pécsi Ügyvédi Kamara 21/VI.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="also_nav">
            <a class="also_nav_button" id="elso" href="#section2"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>ÜZLETI MEDIÁCIÓ</a>
            <a class="also_nav_button" id="masodik" href="#section2"><img src="assets/icon/arrowRight.svg" />CSALÁDJOGI MEDIÁCIÓ</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <!-- MEDIÁCIÓ MENETE -->

      <section class="mediacio_menete" id="section1">
        <div class="textBox2">
          <h1>A mediáció menete</h1>
          <p class="hogyanT">HOGYAN TÖRTÉNIK?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel">
          <section class="responsive">
            <div>
              <div class="elso_elem">
                <img src="assets/icon/search.svg" />
                <h2>Előkészítő ülés</h2>
                <p>A felek külön-külön jelennek meg<br>
                   a mediátor előtt. Tartama 1-1,5<br>
                    óra.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="elso_elem" id="arrow_1">
                <img src="assets/icon/mediation.svg">
                <h2>Mediációs ülés</h2>
                <p>A felmerült probléma mediációs <br>
                  keretek közötti közös <br>
                  megbeszélése 3 óra időkeret áll a <br>
                  felek rendelkezésére.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="elso_elem" id="arrow_2">
                <img src="assets/icon/circle.svg">
                <h2>Különtárgyalás</h2>
                <p>Olyan esetekben, amikor egy <br>
                   adott problémával kapcsolatosan<br>
                    megakad a folyamat.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="elso_elem" id="arrow_3">
                <img src="assets/icon/document.svg">
                <h2>Megállapodás írásba foglalása</h2>
                <p>Lehetőség szerint az ülés végén<br>
                   kerül írásban rögzítésre a felek<br>
                    megállapodása.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="elso_elem" id="arrow_4">
                <img src="assets/icon/flag.svg">
                <h2>Utánkövetés</h2>
                <p>A mediátor az ülést követően<br> megkeresi a 
                  feleket a mediációs<br> folyamat hatásainak,<br>
                   kimenetelének felmérése véget.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div class="szoveg_doboz">
          <p>
            A közvetítő tevékenységéért díj jár és igényt tarthat a 
            felmerült és igazolt költségei <br> megtérítésére, továbbá a díj és 
            költségek előlegezésére is. Az egyes ügyekben <br> felszámítandó díj 
            összegében a közvetítő és a felek szabadon állapodnak meg, <br>
            melyet fő szabályként a felek együttesen viselnek.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="dijazas">
          <p>
            Díjazás: Felenként 8.000 - 15.000 Ft/Óra <br />
            Okiratszerkesztés: 20.000 Ft-tól
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- FONTOS INFORMÁCIÓK -->
      <section class="fontos_informaciok">
        <h1>Fontos információk</h1>
        <h2>Per előtt vagy per alatt?</h2>
        <div class="lista">
          <ul>
            <li>Permegelőző konfliktuskezelés; alternatíva a vita peresítés előtti <br>
              kölcsönös megegyezésen alapuló rendezésére</li>
            <li>illetve lehetőség nyílik folyamaban lévő peres eljárás esetén is az <br>
              érdekelt felek kölcsönös megegyezésével, közvetítő bevonása <br>
              mellett a felek közötti vita peren kívüli rendezésére.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="kozepso_lista">
          <div class="kifizeti">
            <h2>Ki fizeti a díjat?</h2>
            <p class="akozv">
              A közvetítő tevékenységéért díj jár és igényt tarthat a felmerült és igazolt <br>
              költségei megtérítésére, továbbá a díj és költségek előlegezésére is. Az egyes <br> 
              ügyekben felszámítandó díj összegében a közvetítő és a felek szabadon <br>
              állapodnak meg, melyet fő szabályként a felek együttesen viselnek.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="fontos_tudni">
            <h2>Fontos tudni!</h2>
            <p>
              A természetes személyek és más személyek személyi és vagyoni jogaival <br>
               kapcsolatban felmerült azon polgári jogviták közvetítői eljárás keretében <br>
                történő rendezése, amelyekben a felek rendelkezési jogát törvény nem <br>
                 korlátozza, a közvetítői tevékenységről szóló 2002. évi LV. törvény hatálya alá <br> 
                 tartozik.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="milyen_teruleten">
          <p class="mta">
            milyen területen alkalmazható?
          </p>
          <p class="mta2">
            Az élet valamen területén, ahol konfliktushelyzet adódhat. <br> 
            Az alábbi területeket emelném ki:
          </p>
          <div class="lista_tarto">
            <ul>
              <li>Válási helyzet</li>
              <li>Válási helyzet</li>
              <li>Válási helyzet</li>
              <li>Válási helyzet</li>
              <li>Válási helyzet</li>
              <li>Válási helyzet</li>
              <li>Válási helyzet</li>
              <li>Válási helyzet</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lista_tarto">
            <ul>
              
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <!-- ÜZLETI MEDIÁCIÓ -->

      <section class="uzleti_csaladi_mediacio" id="section2">
        <div class="fenti_kartya">
          <div class="fenti_kartya_textBox">
          <h1>Üzleti Mediáció</h1>
          <h2>Pénzkövetelés érvényesítése / Munkaügyi problémák kezelése</h2>
          <p>
            Mondhatjuk, hogy a mediáció az üzleti életben is a jövő útja, hiszen
            ez az a terület <br > ahol leginkább érvényesül az idő pénz elve. A gyors
            vitarendezéssel rengeteg költség <br> takarítható meg.
          </p>
          <a class="fancy-btn" href="/Pages/uzleti-mediacio.html">Részletek</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lenti_kartya">
          <div class="lenti_kartya_textBox">
            <h1>Családjogi mediáció</h1>
            <h2 class="valasi">válási helyzet / vagyonmegosztás / gyermektartásdíj<h2>
            <p class="kartya_jobb_szoveg">
                A család az emberi kapcsolódások legérzékenyebb területe, hiszen 
                <br>ez a társadalom legkisebb egysége, az alap, 
                ahonnan az egyén kiindul.
            </p>
            <a class="fancy-btn" href="/Pages/csaladjogi-mediacio.html">Részletek</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <!-- MAGAMRÓL -->

      <section class="magamrol" id="section3">
          <div class="textBox3">
            <h1>Dr Bokor Beatrix, <br >ügyvéd, mediátor</h1>
            <p>
                Több mint tíz éves szakmai tapasztalatom során is mindvégig arra <br>
                törekedtem, 
                hogy amennyiben lehetséges, együttműködjek a felekkel peren <br> 
                kívüli megállapodás létrehozása érdekében, segítsem őket vitájuk békés,<br> 
                gyors rendezésében.
            </p>
            <a class="fancy-btn" href="/Pages/rolam.html">Részletek</a>
          </div>
          <div class="idezet">
            <div class="idezet_tarto">
              <img src="/assets/icon/">
                <h2>Az igazság nem a mondatokban rejlik, hanem a <br> torzítatlan létezésben. 
                  Az öröklét nem az időben<br> rejlik, hanem az összhang állapotában.
                </h2>
            </div>
                <p>Weöres S</p>
                <img class="bea_karfonas" src="./assets/img/bokorbeatrix.png" alt="">
          </div>
      </section>

      <!-- CONTACT FORM -->

      <section class="contact_form" id="section4">
        <h1>
          Lépjen kapcsolatba <br> és oldjuk meg együtt!
        </h1>
          <div class="contact_form_holder">
          <div class="form">
            <form>
              <div class="felso_form_resz">
                <div class="user-box">
                  <input type="text" name="" required="">
                  <label>Szakterület</labe>
                </div>
                <div class="user-box">
                  <input type="text" name="" required="">
                  <label>Ön neve</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            <div class="also_form_resz">  <div class="user-box" id="mailcim">
              <input type="text" name="" required="">
              <label>E-mail címe</label>
            </div>
            <div class="user-box">
              <input type="text" name="" required="">
              <label>Telefonszáma</label>
            </div></div>
            
              <div class="user-box" id="uzenet">
                <input type="text" name="" required="">
                <label>Üzenet</label>
              </div>
            </form>
            <div class="form_footer">
              <div class="consent">
                <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
                <p>Elfogadom az <span class="avsz">Adatvédelmi Szabályzatot</span></p>
              </div>
              <button class="fancy-btn" id="submit_button" type="submit">Küldés</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contact_inform">
            <div class="contact_inform_holder">
              <ul class="form_lista">
                <div class="form_lista_elem">
                  <img src="/assets/icon/messenger.svg" alt="facebook_messenger_icon">
                </div>
                <div class="form_lista_elem">
                  <img src="/assets/icon/phone.svg" alt="telefonos_elérhetőség_bokor_beatrix"> 
                </div>
                <div class="form_lista_elem">
                  <img src="/assets/icon/email.svg" alt="emailes_elérhetőség_bokor_beatrix">
                </div>
                <div class="form_lista_elem">
                  <img src="/assets/icon/pin.svg" alt="iroda_elhelyezkedés_bokor_beatrix_">
                </div>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="form_lista_szovegek">
              <p>/pecsmediacio</p>
              <p>+36 70 422 7122</p>
              <p>hello@pecsimediacio.hu</p>
              <p> 7623 Pécs, Közraktár u. 5.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>

    <!-- FOOTER -->

    <footer class="main_footer">
        <div class="footer_left">
            <h2>Adószám: 58601851-1-22 Pécsi Ügyvédi Kamara KASZ: 36057848<br> Im nyilvántartási szám: T/002401/1
            </h2>
            <p>
                Minden Jog Fenntartva ©2021 Dr Bokor Beatrix
            </p>
        </div>
      <div class="footer_right">
          <a href="#">Adatvédelmi Szabályzat</a>
          <a href="#">Impresszum</a>
          <a href="#">Kapcsolat</a>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(".responsive").slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        slidesToShow: 4.5,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        responsive: [
        {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1.5,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
        ]
      });
    </script>
    <script src="./main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Experiment by removing all the content in the page and then reintroducing each part until it shows

Answer (score 2):

Its not a margin or padding issue. You have some content overflow in `<section>` and `<header>` elements.

If you apply:

```
header > *,
main > * {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

empty space is gone, but you should find for certain which elements causes content overflow and either make them fully responsive or hide overflow.

Comment: This has solved it, thanks! The "reponsive" nav doesn't see to be so responsive after all, that need a lot of fine tuning.
Thank you so very much for your answer!